Integration on $M^{2n+1}$ with an invariant condition

Given a closed (i.e., compact without boundary) orientable smooth manifold $M$ of dimension $2n+1$ and a smooth vector field $X\in\Gamma(TM)$, suppose two $1$-forms $\alpha,\beta\in\Omega^1(M)$ satisfy
$$\left(\phi_t^X\right)^{\ast}\alpha=\alpha,\quad\left(\phi_t^X\right)^{\ast}\beta=\beta,\quad\forall t\in\mathbb{R}.$$
Here $\phi_t^X$ is the one-parameter group of diffeomorphisms associated to $X$. If $\alpha(X)=\beta(X)=1$, then we have
$$\int_M(\alpha-\beta)\wedge\sum_{j=0}^{n}(d\alpha)^j\wedge(d\beta)^{n-j}=0.$$

My attempt: I realize that the invariant condition above can be interpreted as $\mathcal{L}_X\alpha=\mathcal{L}_X\beta=0$. So by the Cartan's magic formula,
$$0=d(\iota_X\alpha)+\iota_X(d\alpha)=\underbrace{d(\alpha(X))}_{=d(1)=0}+\iota_X(d\alpha)=\iota_X(d\alpha),$$
and similarly
$$\iota_X(d\beta)=0.$$
But I can't see how this can be applied to evaluate the integration. Can anyone give me a hint? Thanks in advance.
p.s. I have heard about Moser's trick and its application to volume forms. I am curious whether this problem has anything to do with that.

Note that $X$ is nonzero at every point. I claim that the integrand is in fact the zero form. At any point $p\in M$, extend $X$ to an (oriented) basis for the tangent space of $M$, taking $X,v_1,\dots,v_{2n}$.
Evaluate (at $p$) $\big((\alpha-\beta)\wedge (d\alpha)^j\wedge (d\beta)^{n-j}\big)(X,v_1,\dots,v_{2n})$ — as usual, by summing over all permutations of the $2n+1$ vectors. Since, as you correctly deduced, $\iota_X (d\alpha) = \iota_X (d\beta) = 0$, the sum reduces to a (nonzero) multiple of
$$(\alpha-\beta)(X)\big((d\alpha)^j\wedge (d\beta)^{n-j}\big)(v_1,\dots,v_{2n}),$$
and this vanishes because $\alpha(X)=\beta(X)=1$.
